# ng cordova media plugin stop method not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova

iam created simple ionic audio app .its play function is work correctly but stop function not working.this is the code please help to fix this
this is controller

```js
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngCordova'])

.controller("ExampleController", function($scope, $ionicPlatform, $cordovaMedia, $ionicLoading) {

   $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
 

      $scope.play = function() {
        var media = new Media(src, null, null, mediaStatusCallback);  
         $cordovaMedia.play(media);
      };

      $scope.pause = function() {
         media.pause();
      };

      $scope.stop = function() {
         media.stop();
      };


 var mediaStatusCallback = function(status) {
        if(status == 1) {
            $ionicLoading.show({template: 'Loading...'});
        } else {
            $ionicLoading.hide();
        }
    }


   });
 
})
```

and this is the html code :

```html
 <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content>
      <button class="button" ng-click="play('http://www.stephaniequinn.com/Music/Commercial%20DEMO%20-%2013.mp3')">Play from internet</button>
      <button class="button" ng-click="stop()">Stop</button>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
```

Comment: Try declaring the variable media outside of the function $scope.play...it is currently out of the scope of the other functions.

Answer (score 0):

Your *media* variable is **local**. So in stop function media is undefined or not the same.

Moreover why are you use methods in different ways? I think you should use the same (e.g. media.play() or $cordovaMedia.stop(media); if it's possible)

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `var media` is out of the scope of $scope.pause and $scope.stop. Try declaring it outside on the $scope.play function like so..

```js
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngCordova'])

.controller("ExampleController", function($scope, $ionicPlatform, $cordovaMedia, $ionicLoading) {

   $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
 
    var media = new Media(src, null, null, mediaStatusCallback);

      $scope.play = function() {
         
         $cordovaMedia.play(media);
      };

      $scope.pause = function() {
         media.pause();
      };

      $scope.stop = function() {
         media.stop();
      };


 var mediaStatusCallback = function(status) {
        if(status == 1) {
            $ionicLoading.show({template: 'Loading...'});
        } else {
            $ionicLoading.hide();
        }
    }


   });
 
})
```

Comment: i do like that but it not working and now both functions are not working

Comment: Where are you defining src? What errors are you seeing now? Please show the errors so we can help

Comment: no errors display in console .i don't know what is the happen.[link](https://archive.org/download/smalinda99_gmail_Www/www.zip) this is my www folder do you can check it?